# footnote with no preceding space

Tags: spacing, footnotes

I would like my footnotes to be separate in the `.tex` file, but rendered without a space in the resulting file.  Can this be done?

Example:
`This is some text\footnote{with a footnote}`
renders as

> This is some text<sup>1</sup>

whereas

```
This is some text
\footnote{with a footnote}
```

renders as

> This is some text <sup>1</sup>

I would like to avoid that extra space, but write my footnote on a different line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Insert a `%` at the end of the line above the `\footnote`

```
This is some text% <--- Important
\footnote{with a footnote}
```

As reference, see [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764) Alternatively, redefine `\footnote` to perform an `\unskip` before continuing on with the regular placement of the `\footnote`:

```
\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}{\unskip\oldfootnote}% Remove any skips inserted before \footnote

%...

This is some text
\footnote{with a footnote}
```